# Add CheckConstraint through __table_args__ dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model with `__table_args__` as a dict:

```py
class User(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    __table_args__ = {
        "mysql_charset": "utf8",
        "mysql_collate": "utf8_general_ci",
    }

    # ...
```

How can I add a `CheckConstraint` to this `__table_args__` dict ? Usually and [sqlalchemy doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/table_config.html#table-configuration) use a `tuple` to show how add `CheckConstraint` to models.

Answer (score -1):

As indicated by documentation:

> Keyword arguments can be specified with the above form by specifying the last argument as a dictionary:

```py
class MyClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sometable'
    __table_args__ = (
            ForeignKeyConstraint(['id'], ['remote_table.id']),
            UniqueConstraint('foo'),
            {'autoload':True}
            )
```